# data.table column deletion speed

Tags: r, data.table

Say I have a large table called 'data'.  I want to delete the column referred to in a variable cI.

This is fast:

```
data = data[, eval(cI) := NULL]
```

This is slow:

```
data[, eval(cI) := NULL]
```

Both work (the 2nd usage doesn't print out (or return) the full table.  What is going on under the hood to make the 2nd method slow?  Obviously, a table copy is involved, but why?

The mystery deepens.  I tried to measure system times, and there's a huge difference for the 2nd method depending on HOW I TIME IT:

```
> system.time(data <- data[, eval(dropI) := NULL])
   user  system elapsed
  0.004   0.000   0.003
> system.time(data[, eval(dropI) := NULL])
   user  system elapsed
  0.004   0.000   0.003
> date(); data[, eval(dropI) := NULL]; date()
[1] "Wed Jan 15 12:31:51 2014"
[1] "Wed Jan 15 12:31:58 2014"
> date(); data <- data[, eval(dropI) := NULL]; date()
[1] "Wed Jan 15 12:32:26 2014"
[1] "Wed Jan 15 12:32:26 2014"`
```

Oh, and I have JIT compiler enabled (setting of 3)

Comment: Please provide some evidence that the second method is slower. After just a bit of quick experimentation, I at least don't see it.

Comment: Strange.  It's very slow for me.  I can't provide the data frame for many reasons, and this seems to be data frame dependent.

Comment: The mystery deepens.  I tried to measure system times, and there's a huge difference for the 2nd method depending on HOW I TIME IT:
`> system.time(data <- data[, eval(dropI) := NULL])
   user  system elapsed
  0.004   0.000   0.003
> system.time(data[, eval(dropI) := NULL])
   user  system elapsed
  0.004   0.000   0.003
> date(); data[, eval(dropI) := NULL]; date()
[1] "Wed Jan 15 12:31:51 2014"
[1] "Wed Jan 15 12:31:58 2014"
> date(); data <- data[, eval(dropI) := NULL]; date()
[1] "Wed Jan 15 12:32:26 2014"
[1] "Wed Jan 15 12:32:26 2014"`

Oh, and I have JIT compiler enabled (setting of 3)

Comment: I have never seen anyone use `date()` to time code before, which makes me suspicious.

Comment: @joran, I'd share your 'suspicion' if the difference weren't so stark.  Also, I re-tested this multiple times.

Comment: I can replicate your observations pretty easily and I'm fairly certain it's the same issue as [FR 5102](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5102&group_id=240&atid=978)

Comment: The fact that no one uses `date()` to time code makes me suspicious because it makes me think that it is a fundamentally flawed way to time things. Whether the differences are large, or how many times you've tested it doesn't matter, really. As eddi implies, using `date()` involves an implicit call to `print()`, so you're timing something you don't mean to be timing at all.

Comment: @joran I disagree - I think this is actually a good way of timing things if the task is to type and execute the code in real time (as opposed to running a script); btw it's not `print` that's slow - it's something else (and I don't know what it is)

Comment: @eddi That's a good point; I didn't say that very clearly; by "implicit call to print()" I meant the difference between typing at the console and hitting enter, and calling print() directly, which apparently does slightly different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clear this up,  @eddi and @joran were on the right track in the comments.

There is absolutely no speed difference between :

```
data = data[, eval(cI) := NULL]
```

and

```
data[, eval(cI) := NULL]
```

**Because, both execute instantly, consistently (0.000s).**  The other answer is just timing `copy(dt)`, see my edit there.

Btw, you don't need the `eval`, just the brackets alone are fine :

```
data = data[, (cI) := NULL]
```

or

```
data[, (cI) := NULL]
```

What's happening is that you're typing these commands on the console.  Since the first is an assignment, the value `data` is returned invisibly and R doesn't print it. R does print the result of the second method.

Just like `data.frame` there is a huge difference in speed in typing `DT` vs `print(DT)` :

```
> DT          # very slow. R copies the whole of DT for some reason
> print(DT)   # very fast. R doesn't copy DT.
```

In the question you concluded a copy was being taken and you were right. But by printing, not by column deletion.

Maybe because `DF` prints the whole of `DF`, that's so slow anyway, nobody notices that R copied `DF` as well before it started to convert the entire `DF` to character form. Since `DT` by default prints the top and bottom of the table, which is very quick, you notice how long R takes to copy it.   Something like this, anyway.

I don't know exactly why this is, but it's been known for a while.  There are some copy reduction changes in the current development version of R and I'm hoping these will curtail the copy that's taken in what's known as *automatic* printing.

In the meantime,  call `print(DT)` explicitly, for memory efficient printing!

Comment: But the point was to AVOID printing.  And in fact no printing occurs (inside the date() block)

Comment: @rimorob Then I'm thoroughly confused now!

Comment: I think you are right about printing, though it's just a hunch: I think when you use a data frame without an obvious function, it prints *somewhere*.  inside a code block, such as date(); df[,]; date();, it probably prints to some null buffer, without realizing that it's not going to be displayed anyway - sort of like the patin space in perl

Comment: @rimorob Oh I see. Yes that could well be it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no evidence that there is a difference in runtime:

```
set.seed(41)
dt <- data.table( a = rnorm(1000000), b = rnorm(1000000), c = rnorm(1000000) )

library( microbenchmark )
library( ggplot2 )

mb <- microbenchmark(  
  m1 = { x <- copy( dt ); x[ , c:= NULL ] },
  m2 = { x <- copy( dt ); x = x[ , c:= NULL ] },
  times = 500
)

# plot
qplot( data = mb, x = expr, y = time, geom = "boxplot", ylab="time [ns]", xlab = "approach" )

# show evidence
t.test( time ~ expr, data = mb )
```

Gives

```
    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  time by expr
t = -0.3622, df = 972.022, p-value = 0.7173
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1437943.7   989846.5
sample estimates:
mean in group m1 mean in group m2 
        10068827         10292876
```

and

[ **EDIT from Matt** ]  These times include the time to `copy(dt)` which appears to be done so that the column can be repeatedly deleted. See how `copy(dt)` appears inside `m1` and `m2` definitions above. This is why the times vary so terribly and why even the best time is quite slow. In short, this benchmark appears to be flawed.  If the `copy(dt)` is excluded from the benchmark, you should find the time to delete a column is consistently almost unmeasurable (i.e. 0.00s) for both methods `m1` and `m2`.  This answer is correct that there's no different between `m1` and `m2`,  but the graph should show a flat line at 0.00s once timing `copy(dt)` is isolated.

[image]

Comment: This is well-researched, and yet see my addendum to the original post: the behavior seems to be different based on how it's observed (an Heisenberg effect!)

Comment: @rimorob In fact, this answer is flawed.

Comment: @MattDowle if one method would have been slower than the other, this would have resulted in a significantly variated mean of the runtimes for a sufficiently large number repetitions (assuming H0 for the runtimes of `copy(dt)` of course). I did not say, that the displayed runtimes are due to the column removal. I said there is no significant difference, which was the original assumption.

Comment: @Beasterfield  But those times are totally dominated by `copy(dt)`. They're nothing to do with column removal.  Replace 'column removal' with any other quick task and you'd reach the same conclusion. You need to time _just_ column removal.

Comment: @MattDowle No offense, but I'm afraid I have to disagree: If the number of iterations is sufficiently large you do not have to time _just_ column removal. Here is a minimal _simulation_ of the problem: `rRuntime <- function( n, copy, remove  ){ rnorm( n, copy, 0.05*copy ) + rnorm( n, remove, 0.05*remove )}`. Just try `t.test( rRuntime(1E5, 10000, 10), rRuntime(1E5, 10000, 1) )`, vs. `t.test( rRuntime(1E5, 10000, 1), rRuntime(1E5, 10000, 1) )`, assuming that copying is 1000 to 10000 times slower than column removal with a standard deviation of the run-to-run runtime of 5%.

Comment: What's run-to-run runtime?

Comment: maybe inartfully expressed. I assume a standard deviation of 5% for the runtime of each statement.